# Upload multiple images in to mysql database in java gui

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, netbeans

I am doing a project for vehicle repair center. In this project I need to upload photos of the damaged vehicle so employees can watch them later.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
path.setText(filePath);
File imgFile = new File(filePath);

try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
```

I tried above, but I can choose only one photo at one time, like this:

[image: like this]

I need these kind of thin

ddddd

Comment: do u want to select multiple image at a time

Comment: yes and add them to mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't do java but a quick glance at the manual suggests you need to enable selection of multiple files:

```
setMultiSelectionEnabled

public void setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean b)

Sets the file chooser to allow multiple file selections.

Parameters:
    b - true if multiple files may be selected
See Also:
    isMultiSelectionEnabled()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled-boolean-

Comment: Now you did java.